# UIView removeFromSuperview inside animation PROPERLY

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Now, this question have partially been asking alot, but none actually considering how (or when) the messages `-viewWillDisappear` & `-viewDidDisappear` are being sent. Almost every example use the following design:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:1.0
    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
    animations:^{
        yourView.alpha = 0;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [yourView removeFromSuperview]; // Called on complete
    }];
```

The problem with this is that these messages will both be sent when de animation ends! 
Now, `-addSubview` can be animated (if put inside the animations-block) which will send the corresponding messages (`-viewWillAppear` & `-viewDidAppear`) with correct timedifference. So naturally one would place `-removeFromSuperview` inside the animations-block. This WILL send the messages correctly, but the view is actually removed instantly making the animation... Well, it won't animate because nothing is left to animate!

Is this intentional from apple and if so, why? How do you do it correctly?

Thanks!

**Edit.**

Just to clearify what I'm doing:
I got a custom segue, vertically animating a Child-ViewController down from top which works as expected with the following code:

```
    -(void)perform{
        UIViewController *srcVC = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
        UIViewController *destVC = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

        destVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, -destVC.view.frame.size.height);
        [srcVC addChildViewController:destVC];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                         animations:^{
                             destVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f);
                             [srcVC.view addSubview:destVC.view];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [destVC didMoveToParentViewController:srcVC];
                         }];
    }
```

Here it will happen in the following order (thanks to `-addSubview` being inside the animations-block):

1. Add childView (will automatically invoke `-willMoveToParentViewController`)
2. `-addSubview` will invoke `-viewWillAppear`
3. When the animation finishes, `-addSubview` will invoke `-viewDidAppear`
4. Manually invoke `-didMoveToParentViewController` inside the completion-block

Above is the exact expected behavior (just like the built-in transitions behave).

With the following code to do the above segue but backwards (with an unwindSegue):

```
-(void)perform{
    UIViewController *srcVC = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;

    srcVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f);
    [srcVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.5f
                     animations:^{
                         srcVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, -srcVC.view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [srcVC.view removeFromSuperview]; // This can be done inside the animations-block, but will actually remove the view at the same time ´-viewWillDisappear´ is invoked, making no sense!
                         [srcVC removeFromParentViewController];
                     }];
}
```

the flow will be like this:

1. Manually invoke `-willMoveToParentView:nil` to notify that it will be removed
2. When the animation finishes, both `-viewWillDisappear` & `-viewDidDisappear` will be invoked simultaneously (wrong!) and `-removeFromParentViewController` will automatically invoke `-didMoveToParentViewController:nil`.

And if I now move `-removeFromSuperview` in to the animations-block, the events will be sent correctly but the view is removed when the animation starts instead of when the animation finishes (this is the part that makes no sense, following how `-addSubview` behaves).

Comment: What you're seeing is what you should expect since you're removing the view instantaneously. What's the problem with viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear being called one right after the other? What do you want to do in these methods that this is a problem?

Comment: `yourView` seems to be a `UIView` object and `-viewWillAppear`, `-viewDidAppear`, `-viewWillDisappear`, `-viewDidDisappear` are all `UIViewController`'s instance methods, not `UIView`'s

Comment: @rdelmar In my case It's an UnwindSegue, which at ´-viewWillDisappear´ should start a "scrollUp"-animation simultaneously to create a nice effect. None the less it's important that messages are sent when you expect them to to work in a logical way for other coders.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yes you are correct, I should've been more clear on that. My point was just that these messages are sent from actions being done on UIViews, that's why I didn't mention a VC.

Comment: I think your problem might be using the wrong animation method to accomplish your task. You might want to look into the UIViewController method, transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion: (or perhaps the UIView methods, transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:, or transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:). It's hard to advise you further without knowing what specifically you're trying to do.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks, will check that out! But I still just think it's odd how the ´-addSubview´ & ´-removeFromSuperview´ (corresponding methods) behave differently... But yeah, maybe I'll just have to settle for a special-case when unwinding with a custom segue.

Comment: See my edit for more details about my specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about removing view controller, because, `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` are method of view controller.

`viewWillDisappear:` will be called from completion block, not earlier, because this is the place where you said that you want to remove subview from main view.

If you want to remove some property before that point, then in child controller override `willMoveToParentViewController:` method. This method will be called before animation block.
Here's code example:

```
//Prepare view for removeing.
[self.childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.childViewController.view.alpha = 0;
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self.childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     [self.childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                 }];
```

So, the flow will be:

1. First `willMoveToParentViewController:` with nil parameter will be called
2. Animation block will start and view will set it's alpha property to 0
3. When animation finish, completion block will start to execute...
4. `[self.childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];` will be called first
5. Then `viewWillDissapear:` in childViewController will be called
6. Then `[self.childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];`
7. And at the end `viewDidDissapear:` in childViewController will execute.

Pre request for this flow is that you embed childViewController with code like this:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.childViewController];    
[self.view addSubview:self.childViewController.view];
[self.childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Yes, these messages are sent to an instance of View Controller, but are invoked because of state-changes made to UIView, which is why I explained it that way.
I am actually performing an UnwindSegue, which is basically just a vertical slide up (out). Your solution still doesn't solve the problem because the messages ´-viewWillDisappear´ & ´-viewDidDisappear´ are still called simultaneously (because as you say they only have to do with ´-removeFromSuperview´). Just like I explained with ´-addSubview´, I need these events to occur in sync with the animation.

Comment: Did you try to remove call of "-scrollUp" method out of "-viewWillDissapear:"? Maybe you can post notification to start the "-scrollUp" method, and not to start it from "-viewWillDissapear:". That way you don't depend on any method which you don't have control.

Comment: Sure, that is an option but I'd like to avoid that as much as possible because I want to make stuff like these generelized (since for example this unwind segue it is not only ment for use in one single project). 
This just seems odd to me, because if the behaviour is so specific with the ´-addSubview´, then ´-removeFromSuperview´ should logically work in the same way... If you try ´-removeFromSuperview´ inside the animations-block you'll see what I mean. Why would Apple make it so that ´-viewWillDisappear´ is called correctly, but the view is actually removed at this same point in time?